# Unable to set up 123-reg SSL's intermediate certificate on WHM?

Tags: ssl

I recently had an SSL certificate set for a domain on my VPS. Later I found out that it required an intermediate certificate to function properly on all devices.

The SSL in question is [123-reg's basic SSL](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/ssl-certificates/123-ssl-certificates.shtml).

They are saying that the intermediate certificate is for this package is [here](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/SSL-Certificates/SSL-Explained/where-can-i-obtain-a-intermediate-root-ca-certificate-for-my-ssl-certificate-2591/).

As far as I understand (my sysadmin skills are quite basic) I need to go to

`WHM` >> `SSL/TLS` » `Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain`,

pick out the certificate I want to use/update, and paste the root ca provided by 123 reg into the `Certificate Authority Bundle` field.

However when I do so, it tells gives me the following error:

`The CA bundle does not match the certificate.`

Any recommendations on what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understand you have the intermediate-certificate issue (don't know how to put it).
What you need is the following 3 things:

1: Your domain certificate
2: Your intermediateCertificateAuthority
3: The certificate of the RootCA

Now open them all 3 in notepad and make a new crt file with the following structure:

```
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------
Certificate of Yourdomain.crt
------END CERTIFICATE---------
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------
Certificate of YourIntermediateCertificateAuthority.crt
------END CERTIFICATE---------
------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-------
Certificate of RootCA.crt
------END CERTIFICATE---------
```

Where you put the content of course in the right places.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. What do I do with the crt file afterwards?

Comment: You want to upload it to, so the server can serve it.